# Update multiple column with bind variable using cx_Oracle.executemany()

Tags: python-3.x, cx-oracle

I have been trying to update some columns of a database table using cx_Oracle in Python. I created a list named check_to_process which is a result of another sql query. I am creating log_msg in the program based on success or failure and want to update same in the table only for records in check_to_process list. When I update the table without using bind variable <*MESSAGE = %s*>, it works fine. But when I try to use bind variable to update the columns it gives me error :

```
cursor.executemany("UPDATE apps.SLCAP_CITI_PAYMENT_BATCH SET MESSAGE = %s, "
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
```

Below is the code, I am using:

```
import cx_Oracle
connection = cx_Oracle.connect(user=os.environ['ORA_DB_USR'], password=os.environ['ORA_DB_PWD'], dsn=os.environ['ORA_DSN'])
cursor = connection.cursor()

check_to_process = ['ACHRMUS-20-OCT-2021 00:12:57', 'ACHRMUS-12-OCT-2021 16:12:01']
placeholders = ','.join(":x%d" % i for i,_ in enumerate(check_to_process))

log_msg = 'Success'

cursor.executemany("UPDATE apps.SLCAP_CITI_PAYMENT_BATCH SET MESSAGE = %s, "
                       "PAYMENT_FILE_CREATED_FLAG='N' "
                       "WHERE PAYMENT_BATCH_NAME = :1",
                       [(i,) for i in check_to_process], log_msg, arraydmlrowcounts=True)
```

Many thanks for suggestions and insights!

Answer (score 0):

Your code has an odd mix of string substitution (the `%s`) and bind variable placeholders (the `:1`).  And odd code that creates bind variable placeholders that aren't used.  Passing log_msg the way you do isn't going to work, since `executemany()` syntax doesn't support string substitution.

You probably want to use some kind of IN list, as shown in the cx_Oracle documentation [Binding Multiple Values to a SQL WHERE IN Clause](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/bind.html#binding-multiple-values-to-a-sql-where-in-clause).  Various solutions are shown there, depending on the number of values and frequency that the statement will be re-executed.

Use only bind variables.  You should be able to use `execute()` instead of `executemany()`.  Effectively you would do:

```
cursor.execute("""UPDATE apps.SLCAP_CITI_PAYMENT_BATCH 
                  SET MESSAGE = :1 
                  WHERE PAYMENT_BATCH_NAME IN (something goes here - see the doc)""", 
  bind_values)
```

The bottom line is: read the documentation and review examples like [batch_errors.py](https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/blob/main/samples/batch_errors.py).  If you still have problems, refine your question, correct it, and add more detail.

Comment: The doc does not provide an example of how to pass two bind variables like below:

`UPDATE table 
set column4 = :value_from_a_variable,
column5 = :current_date
WHERE column1 in ([list of values derived during runtime])`

Comment: That doc does show passing multiple bind variables in - because the IN list contains multiple binds..  Also see 'named binds' in https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#inbind   Name each bind variable placeholder in your SQL statement with a different name, and then use a value for each name when you pass the bind parameter to `execute()`.  If you update your question with what you've tried, I can discuss it further.